# ajax stop page scrolling

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am retrieving data from server using ajax, when i make an ajax call, i show an overlay div with an animated image,

everything is working perfectly fine, but i have an issue, whenever i make an ajax call. my page scroll to top, i used this code to stop scrolling,

```
function startAjax() { // calling before ajax call
    $('html, body').css('overflow','hidden');
}

function stopAjax() { // calling after ajax call
    $('html, body').css('overflow','auto'); 
}
```

it did the magic, but again i encountered an issue, i used datepicker in my page, and auto overflow enable scrolling and my datepicker drowned down the screen,

please give me any nice idea to accomplish this.

Comment: can you provide the `css` of your overlay `div`. i guess the problem is in the `css`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's scrolling to top, it is likely caused by the link(?) you're using having the href attribute of `#`

If you're using a link, just use `return false` or `event.preventDefault();` to stop it from following the `href` attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", "#link", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault().
    //or
    return false;
});
```

Comment: i am sorry for the late reply due to weekend, i am calling ajax on multiple events like, 'onChange', 'onBlur', 'onClick', according to your solution, how do i fix this..

Comment: @Rick Peck  I too have the same problem of page scrolling , in my case its button I added e.preventDefault() but its not working , what I should I do